# How to resize image to specific amount of MB/KB in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Is there a way of resizing the images lets say from 5MB to 1MB or from 5MB to 500KB in NodeJs without using any paid services/sdk (maybe some npm libraries)

The case: I want to let my clients upload images, which I will be storing on AWS S3. But for optimization and price optimization purposes I would like to reduce all images to **specific** size

Could you please share a solution and if there are any pitfalls?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you trying to reduce the pixel count or the image quality or both to achieve the target size?  If reducing the pixel count, what are the requirements on pixel count?  And, are these all JPGs?

Comment: FYI, the [JIMP library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) is commonly used from nodejs.  It has methods for `.resize()` and `.quality()`, both of which will affect the MB/KB of the image.  It isn't clear to me that it lets you target a specific MB, so you'd probably have to first resize to a specific number of pixels and quality and if the image is still too large, then reduce the quality further.

Comment: Another one to look at is [sharp.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp).